# perl foreach array of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, push

I have 7 arrays (@p1 @p2 @p3 @p4 @p5 @p6 @p7) and I want to want to push a value to each array, but I'm having trouble making it work. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
$something="some value";
@arrays=qw/@p1 @p2 @p3 @p4 @p5 @p6 @p7/;

foearch $line (@arrays) {
     push $line, $something;
     }
```

Comment: Be sure to always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qw` operator takes all the values between the delimiters and returns a list of strings of those values. So in your example:

```
@arrays=qw/@p1 @p2 @p3 @p4 @p5 @p6 @p7/;
```

actually sets `@arrays` to:

```
('@p1', '@p2', '@p3', '@p4', '@p5', '@p6', '@p7')
```

which is simply a list of strings.

What you want to do instead is to set `@arrays` to a list of *references* to your set of arrays. You can take a reference by preceding the sigil of a variable with a `\`.

So, change

```
@arrays = qw/@p1 @p2 @p3 @p4 @p5 @p6 @p7/;
```

to

```
@arrays = (\@p1, \@p2, \@p3, \@p4, \@p5, \@p6, \@p7);
```

By dereferencing each individual array reference in your loop, (which `push` does for you automatically in perl) you can `push` what you need into each original array.

See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for details on how array references work.

Comment: Mentioning `for my $i (0..6) { push @{ $matrix[$i] }, $something; }` seems necessary.

Comment: `@arrays = \(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7);`